# Using Azure AD for authenticate users to our Meteor by SAML = AADSTS65005

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have used Azure Active Directory and registered an APP:

1. Name = MyWebClient
2. Type = WebApp
3. SignonURL = https://myserverurl.de
4. Reply URL = https://myserverurl.de

So now My Client is sending a SAML request to AzureAD on the SAML Endpoint provided by Azure AD and the Login appears. So far so good.

When i try to login however, i end up with this error:

```
AADSTS65005: The application MyWebClient is currently not supported for your company 'MyCompany'. Your company is currently in an unmanaged state and needs an Administrator to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of 'MyCompany' before the application 'MyWebClient' can be provisioned.
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's nothing wrong with your app, but your tenant configuration.  I'd recommend getting in contact with the tenant admin (if that's not you) and verifying planta.de on the tenant, as the error says.